# Creating a method that returns an array

Tags: c#, arrays, methods

I'm to create a helper method that returns a new array whose elements are the square of an original array. But when I run the code, the console returns "System.Double[]". How can I fix this?

Here's the method code:

```
static double[] powerOfTwo(int[] arr)
        {
            double[] elevatedPower = new double[10];
            elevatedPower[0] = Math.Pow(arr[0], 2);
            elevatedPower[1] = Math.Pow(arr[1], 2);
            elevatedPower[2] = Math.Pow(arr[2], 2);
            elevatedPower[3] = Math.Pow(arr[3], 2);
            elevatedPower[4] = Math.Pow(arr[4], 2);
            elevatedPower[5] = Math.Pow(arr[5], 2);
            elevatedPower[6] = Math.Pow(arr[6], 2);
            elevatedPower[7] = Math.Pow(arr[7], 2);
            elevatedPower[8] = Math.Pow(arr[8], 2);
            elevatedPower[9] = Math.Pow(arr[9], 2);

            return elevatedPower;
        }
```

And the code to print it in the console:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double[] powerValues = powerOfTwo(new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10});
            Console.Write(powerValues);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: What do you wanna print? Your all squared values?

Comment: This will always show this kind of value, you need to use for loop to display whole array.

Comment: print elements of array instead of printing array itself

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your method works fine. But when you do `Console.WriteLine(powerValues)`, the compiler calls `ToString()` method of the datatype which is `System.double[]`.

```
foreach(var value in powerValues)
    Console.WriteLine(value);
```

With Linq, `using System.Linq;`

```
var powerValues = (new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}).Select(x => x*x);
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you are *not* printing your values. You try to print your array which returns it's full type name as `System.Double[]` since `ToString` calls it which is called by `Console.Write` explicitly.

You don't even need such a method. Just use [`Enumerable.Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) to generate `IEnumerable<int>` which contains squared values like;

```
var values = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
foreach (var value in values.Select(i => i * i))
{
     Console.Write(value); // 149162536496481100
}
```

And I would use `Console.WriteLine` to writing those values in separate lines each or put at least a white space after them if you choose `Write` like `Console.Write(value + " ")`

Answer (score 2):

When you calling `Console.Write(powerValues);` actually call  `Console.Write(powerValues.ToString());`ToString returns a string that represents the current object. For double[] this is "System.Double[]".
Change your code like this :

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double[] powerValues = powerOfTwo(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 });
        foreach (var value in powerValues)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Write Your code in just simple one line using below code.

```
new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }.ToList().ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i * i));
```

and each value are display in new line so result are also good compare to other.